# Does a thread waked after wait() and got the monitor again continues from the next instruction after wait() or from the beginning?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

Suppose a `thread_1` does this:

```
synchronized(o) {
    dosomthing1;
    o.wait();
    dosomthing2;
}
```

Suppose thread_1 was awakened, blocked on getting `o` monitor, got it. What will be the next `thread_1` instruction? `dosomthing1` or `dosomthing2`?

Comment: `dosomething2`. You can write simple program to verify that, why ask?

Comment: because the program I write possible contains bugs but I wanna learn this 100% right

Comment: @J.J.Beam Creating small, self-contained, and simple programs to test this behavior is an important skill to learn and develop. A testbench as simple as `System.out.println("1"); o.wait(); System.out.println("2");` with another thread notifying the object after a delay would give you the answer you want, without being so complicated as to make it impossible to figure out if your program contains "possible bugs".

Comment: Since I don't know such easy java things my small program possible contains bugs, but I wanna learn right things

Comment: Why do you think it would be dosomething1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose we have 2 methods `printFirst()` will print from 0 to 5 and `printSecond()` will print from 0 to 10

```
void printFirst() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}

void printSecond() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

These two methods are going to used by `Thread-0` as you can see first in the `try catch` first it will call `printFirst` method after the method has finished its work `wait()` method will put the current on `WAIT STATE` and any code below the `wait()` will not be executed until `notify` is invoked.

```
synchronized void testThreadWait(){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" starting to work");
    try {
        printFirst();
        wait();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "starts");
        printSecond();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

The other method will be executed from Thread-1 and it will print something and it will `notify`() the thread that is in current `wait` state

```
synchronized void testThreadNotify(){
    System.out.println("\n" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "starting to work");
    System.out.println("Thread one is waiting");
    System.out.println("Preparing to notify Thread One");
    notify();
}
```

When wait() method is invoked `Thread-0` will continue to do his job in this case will call `printSecond()` the method that was below the wait() method , and it will print numbers from 0-10

Full code

```
class TestThread{

    void printFirst() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

    void printSecond() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

    synchronized void testThreadWait(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" starting to work");
        try {
            printFirst();
            wait();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "starts");
            printSecond();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("This will be printed after wait");
    }

    synchronized void testThreadNotify(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "starting to work");
        System.out.println("Thread one is waiting");
        System.out.println("Preparing to notify Thread One");
        notify();
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final TestThread c=new TestThread();
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){c.testThreadWait();}
        }.start();
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){c.testThreadNotify();}
        }.start();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Thread-0 starting to work
0 1 2 3 4 5 
Thread-1starting to work
Thread one is waiting
Preparing to notify Thread One
Thread-0starts
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 <--- prints only printSecond()
```

Here you can see that when Thread-0 is being notified it is printing only the second method that was below the `wait()` method